# PendingIntent not always launching in android

Tags: android, push-notification

I am  creating notifications after getting GCM push notification message.That's all done. But when i click on the notification, sometimes it's not launching(PendingIntent). Mostly the issue comes when i click soon after getting the notification. The pending intent is actually my first login page itslf. This is the source code..

```
public void createNotification(Context context, String message) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            "My notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL ;
    Intent intent;


    intent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
    intent.putExtra("pushNoti", "pushNoti");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "my Alert",
            message, pendingIntent);

    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

Here context is getting from the GCM onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)..

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Also my app is in background when i do this..

Answer (score 0):

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

From the doc:

> public void notify (int id, Notification notification)
>
> Since: API Level 1
>   Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **id**: An identifier for this notification unique within your application.
>
> **notification**: A Notification object describing what to show the user. Must not be null.

Instead of 0, try using an identifier that is unique for each notification within your app.